# VB.NET crear paginas tabcontrol

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un form1 llamado NativeMethods con 1 tabcontrol1 y 1 pestaña en ese tabcontrol1.

Por otro lado, tengo un botón:

```
Private Sub Button7_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    Dim frmNewForm As New NativeMethods
    Dim NewTab As TabPage = frmNewForm.TabPage1
    NewTab.Text = TabControl1.TabCount + 1.ToString
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(NewTab)
End Sub
```

Que se encarga de crear otra pestaña en ese tabcontrol1 copiando la existente.

Hasta aquí bien, pero cuando intento hacer el proceso para añadir una tercera ventana no ocurre nada.

Revisando mi código supongo que no se está creando la tercera ventana porque ya se ha creado al generar la segunda, por lo que las detecta repetidas.

Alguna idea para que esto funcione, pudiendo añadir varias ventanas?

Comment: que es `NativeMethods` ?

Comment: el nombre del form principal, disculpa!

Comment: Intentas crear una tercera ventana o una tercera TabPage?, por que el código que manejas puede crear las N TabPages posibles.

Comment: una tercera tabpage, hoy me he dado cuenta que si añado una tabpage desde la tabpage1 me funciona, pero desde la tabpage2 no puedo agregar tabpages, (la tabpage2 es una tabpage con inherits de la tabpage1 así que deberían ser iguales...)

Comment: interesante tu codigo, me sirvio para mucho, pero tengo una pregunta, Con que nombre se crean los controles en la nueva pesataña?